# New Twitter Widget font color change

Tags: twitter, widget, textcolor

managed to find ways to customize the twitter widget. All im after now is to change the overall colors of the text within each tweet, not the links as i have changed this. I have set the theme to dark so that the text is light but ideally i would like all the text to be white and not faint grey. Looked endlessly for a solution, unfortunately not as easy as the original way of embedding twitter walls but thought id ask anyway on ere.

cheers for your help/time.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE. 
For example to change the text color.

```
 $(window).load(function() {
     $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find('head').append( '.p-name { color:#fff !important; } ' );
 }
```

Note the difference between load() and ready() function.

```
$(window).load // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
$(window).ready // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
```